# Manga with a cultivator who trains in his mind to get stronger

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, cultivation

I'm looking for a manhwa where the main character gets a system in a modern world where cultivation is a thing to the entire world.

He gets a system to learn cultivation techniques and he learns them while fighting monsters from the modern world but where he trains is in his mind, and it increases his power the stronger the monster is the stronger he becomes.

Comment: Some modern cultivators at https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/d2ie12/whats_a_good_modern_day_cultivator_series_or/

Comment: 1. Does the MC use some sort of machinery to train? 2. Are there two different worlds he lives in? 3. If the 2 answer is a "yes", does he train in the modern world and go back to medieval/ancient/past times or is it the other way around?

Comment: 1. If your answers are "yes" -> "yes" -> "he trains in the past and comes back to the future", then I assume you are talking about Murim Login

Comment: And also we would like to know if it was coloured or not and any other details you remember. Though you might deem those as insignificant, it usually is the prerequisite to finding the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The querent posted a matching work in the comments, *[Level Up in the Mirror](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/level-up-in-the-mirror)* by Runaway loli:

[image: Front cover of Level Up in the Mirror]

> My name is Feng Yun. No cultivation resources, penniless? It doesn’t matter, I have a mirror, as long as it shines, whether you are human or beast, whether you are dead or alive, all things are projected out. What martial arts techniques, what heavenly treasures, what weapons, even talent qualifications are all projected for you!

The basic idea behind it is that Feng Yun has been isekaied into a world of cultivation, but has no natural talent until his cheat skill kicks in, tied to a mirror necklace he wears, which allows him to take someone reflected in the necklace, and fight them virtually inside his mind, gaining "drops" of their abilities if he defeats them.